# Match today's week with a week in a range of dates

Tags: excel, vba

How do I match the cell with todays week in the week of a range of Dates?
In row 5 are the Dates, this row will be hidden (FIND is not possible to use)
Today is the 13th august.
It is in the same week as the 15th august. (see picture)
D5 would be the answer.

I tried:

```
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim TodaysWeek As Integer

    TodaysWeek = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date, vbMonday)
    
    Set rngFound = .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TodaysWeek, Application.worksheetfunktion.WeekNum(DateRange, vbMonday), 0))
```

I prefer not to use a helper row with the week number.
But if there is no easy way with VBA to find it, I can use it. In this case I know how to do it.

[image]

I found a solution. See my answer below.

Comment: So use week() on the current date and again on the target date - if they match good.

Comment: @SolarMike I guess you mean weeknum() if not, I don't understand. I can't find week()

Comment: I edited my question, to make it more clear.

Comment: I think you can go back and look at the edits of the answer that were made, however I"m pretty sure the end result the same.

Comment: @pgSystemTester wow! That formula can handle any weekday. I added it in my own answer. Thank you! Great stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours and with help of pgSystemTester's solution, I managed to solve it.
Thanks to all who came with solutions.

```
Sub FindWeek_in_DateRange()

    Dim rngFound  As Range
    Dim Daterange As Range
    Dim DatePosition_in_Daterange As Integer
    
    
    With MyTest
        Set Daterange = .Range("C5:Z5")
       
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            'this is the worksheet formula
            '=MATCH(TODAY()+(WEEKDAY(cell_Startdatum;11)-WEEKDAY(TODAY();11));C5:Z5;0)
            
            'this is the worksheet function of above formula to match todays week with the week of a range of dates
            DatePosition_in_Daterange = .Match(CLng(Date + .Weekday(MyTest.Range("cell_Startdatum"), 11) - .Weekday(Date, 11)), Daterange, 0)
        End With
    
        Set rngFound = .Cells(.Range("cell_Startdatum").Row, DatePosition_in_Daterange + .Range("cell_Startdatum").Column - 1)
        
        rngFound.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

The formula above works only if the weekday of each date is the same.
With this formula it can be any weekday.:

```
=MAX(FILTER(COLUMN($C$5:$Z$5);($C$5:$Z$5<=D17)*(ISNUMBER($C$5:$Z$5)))-COLUMN(C5)+1)
```

I don't use whole column 5:5 that's why one has to add the start column +1 at the end of the formula.
Great thanks to pgSystemTester for this fantastik solution!

Comment: what a relief to the rest of us to know you have solved your issue. Given you have an SO rating of over 400, I'm not sure how you would figure making your own answer was the right call vs accepting an answer? If multiple answers were useful give both an upvote. Again, glad you got it figured it out, but you might want to revisit the expectations of the webiste you're on.

Comment: @pgsytemtester Don't understand everything you are writing. My English is not that great. However I voter the answers up which I understood and found helpful. For the other answer I said a thank you in the comment plus why I couldn't use it, but that comment was not liked, so I removed it. After this question I understand many other people better when they ask a non understandable question. I had great difficulty in expressing it more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

***Simplified to avoid filter Requirement***

This formula will always return the `Monday` of the current week:

```
=TODAY()+(2-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))
```

Use a [Match Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function) for `row 5` (or wherever your dates are) to find the column:

```
=MATCH(TODAY()+(2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())),5:5,0)
```

Throw that into an [index function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) and it will return the cell (same value as the Monday formula, so maybe not needed?).

```
=INDEX(5:5,1,MATCH(TODAY()+(2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())),5:5,0))
```

Comment: First you posted a second answer with filter function. Do you still have it, I would like to look at it. Because with this formula =MATCH(TODAY()+(WEEKDAY(D5;11)-WEEKDAY(TODAY();11));5:5;0) the weekday of all the dates must be the same. That is also the case with my needs. But an other time I or someone else might need it more flexible. So I'm wondering if your first formula was so dynamic that it could find a week no matter of weekday.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the "hard" way

```
Function findFirstCurrWeek(rg As Range) As Range
    
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = VBA.Now
    
    Dim curWeek As Long
    curWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(dt, vbMonday)
    
    Dim dtWeek As Long
    Dim sngCell As Range
    
    For Each sngCell In rg
        If Len(sngCell.Value) > 0 Then
            dtWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(sngCell.Value, vbMonday)
            If dtWeek = curWeek Then
                'Debug.Print sngCell.Address
                Set findFirstCurrWeek = sngCell
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

You could test it like that

```
Function FindLastcolumn(rg As Range) As Long
        
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    FindLastcolumn = rg.Find("*", , Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Exit Function
EH:
    FindLastcolumn = 0
End Function

Sub TestIt()
    Dim rg As Range
    
    Set rg = Rows(5)
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = FindLastcolumn(rg)
    Set rg = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, lastCol))  ' Data in row 5
        
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rgFound = findFirstCurrWeek(rg)
    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No hit"
    Else
        Debug.Print rgFound.Address
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @Prema Stack Overflow is not a place to whine about solutions being too hard -- especially when your question isn't exactly clear.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the range:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findIt()
    Dim theHiddenRow As Range, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim thisWeek As Long
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
Set theHiddenRow = ws.Rows(5)

With WorksheetFunction
    thisWeek = .WeekNum(Date)
    For Each c In theHiddenRow.Cells
        If IsDate(c) Then
            If .WeekNum(c) = thisWeek Then
                Debug.Print c.Value, c.Address, .WeekNum(c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

- if the macro is too slow, you can rewrite it to use a vba array